# sql query in shortcode not working

Tags: shortcode

I have a custom table `'wp-products'` in WordPress with the following fields

```
id (primary key)  e.g 1
make              e.g. ford
model             e.g. mustang
price             e.g. 17500.00

id (primary key)  e.g 2
make              e.g. dodge
model             e.g. pheonix
price             e.g. 77500.00
```

what I want to do is create a shortcode e.g. `[product_price id=2]` that returns the price value associated with id number 2 in this table e.g. `77500.00`. I have tried several ways and ended up with this (below)
I put this code in `functions.php`

```
function product_price_func( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $output = '';
    $product_id = '';

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'id' => 'no id found',
    ), $atts, 'product_price' );

    $product_id = $atts['id'];


    $product_price = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT price FROM wp-products WHERE id={$product_id}", ARRAY_A);

    foreach ( $product_price as $the_price ) 
    {   
      $output = $the_price->price;
    }
    return "Product Price: $" . $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'product_price', 'product_price_func' );
```

However, this returns an empty result. I have checked that it passes `id` correctly but cannot get the query to return the value associated with `id=2`.

Comment: this would be simpler with a custom post type instead of custom table, but `get_var` would be the more appropriate method for what you're currently doing.

Comment: Thanks Milo for the quick reply. I have managed to work it out now. After hours of no result all I had to do was post the question on stackexchange and magically the answer comes to me 30 minutes later without the need for someone to help me. Just like when you ask your lecturer for help and explain the problem and while you are explaining it you work out the answer and the lecturer does not have to do anything. Magic, that's what it is, magic (aaaargh!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked it out and here are the steps to what I did to get it working

1. created a custom table in the wordpress database (called it wp-products)
2. this table had the following fields: id, make, model, price
3. Created a shortcode to retrieve the price. Shortcode looks like this [product_price id=2] where id=2 is the price value for item 2 in the table.
4. wrote the shortcode function for this and put it in functions.php in my themes directory.
5. Modified my original code by

- adding $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'products';
- Changed the query to: $product_price = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT price FROM " . $table_name ." WHERE id={$product_id}", ARRAY_A);
- changed the foreach statement to $output = $the_price['price'];

6. added the shortcode into the page location where I wanted to display the code.

Here is the code that works, I hope it helps

```
function product_price_func( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;
```

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'products';

$atts = shortcode_atts(
array(
  'id' => 'no id found',
), $atts, 'product_price' );

$product_id = $atts['id'];

$product_price = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT price FROM " . $table_name ." WHERE id={$product_id}", ARRAY_A);

foreach ( $product_price as $the_price ) 
  { 
    $output = $the_price['price'];
  }

return "Product Price: $" . $output;
```

}
add_shortcode( 'product_price', 'product_price_func' );